# React Bootstrap checkbox issue: Form.Check working as a text input instead of a checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, frontend, react-bootstrap

Im using [react bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) to create a form on my app. I used the [boilerplate](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/forms/checks-radios/#rb-docs-content) to create checkbox inputs, but for some reason, its working as a text input instead of a checkbox.

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening. Theres no error on the console.

I already imported the bootstrap css styles to the project too, so its not that.

Can somebody help?

Comment: I haven't used bootstrap in a while but I'm going to guess it's because you're not surrounding each `<Form.Check>` inside `<Form.Group>` - You can see what I mean in the [docs](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/forms/overview/#rb-docs-content) where they surround each form piece inside a `<Form.Group>`.

Comment: I tried this but didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.
Its `type="checkbox"` instead of `type="check"`.

Cant believe i spent almost 2 hours trying to fix this.

Comment: Please mark this question as solved then.

Comment: This is essentially a typo question and should be closed.